# Let's think of a creative name for our chatroom

Tags: discussion, chat

Our current chatroom name is "The Drug Store." Look at all the creative names others have thought up:

- "Root Access" for Super User
- "The DMZ" for Security
- "The Renderfarm" for Blender
- "The Litter Box" for Pets
- "The Hangar" for Aviation
- "You Are Here" for Travel
- "The Water Cooler" for The Workplace
- "The Whiteboard" for Programmers
- "The Nineteenth Byte" for Code Golf
- "The Junk Drawer" for Lifehacks
- "The Percolator" for Coffee
- "The Waiting Room" for Health
- etc...

Can we think of a better name for our chatroom?

Only one idea per answer, please. Vote up the ideas that you like!

Stolen from the [Coffee Meta](https://coffee.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/lets-think-of-a-creative-name-for-our-chatroom/), which was stolen from [Lifehacks meta](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/lets-think-of-a-creative-name-for-our-chatroom), which was in turn stolen from [PPCG meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1005/lets-think-of-a-creative-name-for-our-chatroom). Thanks to Doorknob for writing all of the previous ones. :P

Comment: It would also be nice if people could perhaps be more active in chat. . . We're not off to a friendly start.

Comment: @HDE226868: I agree, chat's a great way to get people involved. It'd be great to encourage people to chat more.

Answer (score 10):

### The Sidebar

Answer (score 8):

How about naming it

### The Courtroom

Answer (score 5):

#### Chambers

These are more characters.

Comment: I think I would support this if it were In-Chambers

Comment: Sorry to bug you here; but since I can't post in chat, I figured I'll let you know: your site audience might appreciate this little legal gem for this Star Wars season: http://thefarrlawfirm.com/2015/12/30/the-theft-of-the-falcon/ . Feel free to post to site chat if you think it's a good fit there.

Answer (score 4):

I propose:

## The Bar

My proposal is so short that I have to add these extra characters.

Answer (score 2):

perhaps
**The Jurybox/room**?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe we can use "**The Legalese**"

Answer (score -4):

### The         Jailhouse

Answer (score -5):

How about

**The dock**